# How to add functionality to my try again button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a written a code which generates two numbers and asks user to calculate its sum and input the result. Program works fine but what I want is to add a button which again asks user to input the result and verify that. The problem I am facing is that the entry is not being cleared and another window is opening below the original window with same entry.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
window = tk.Tk()
content = tk.StringVar()
def startgame():
    number1 = random.randint(10, 51)
    number2 = random.randint(10, 51)
    sum_of_num = number1 + number2

    def checkresult():
        global content
        i = int(content.get())
        if i == sum_of_num:
            label = tk.Label(window, text = "Correct Result", fg = "blue").pack()
        else:
            label = tk.Label(window, text = "Incorrect result!! Try again.", fg = "red").pack()


    window.title("Number Guessing Game")
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "Let's begin the Quiz", fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "---------------------", fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "Given two numbers", fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = number1, fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = number2, fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "Add these two numbers and enter the result", fg = "blue").pack()

    sum_of_numbers = tk.Entry(window, textvariable = content)
    sum_of_numbers.pack()
    sum_of_numbers.focus_set()

    button_to_check_result = tk.Button(window, text="Check whether answer is correct", fg = "red", command = checkresult).pack()


startgame()    
button_to_try_again = tk.Button(window, text="Try Again !!", fg = "red", command = startgame).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I expect the same window again with cleared inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to clear the window, you need to pack all the labels into a single frame. For that, you need to first import ttk from tkinter:

```
from tkinter import ttk
fr = ttk.Frame()
```

Now, all the master value for the variables need to be changed from 'window' to 'fr'. But as a simpler way, what I have done is to use the variable 'window' as the frame. So,

```
root= tk.Tk()
window = ttk.Frame(root)
```

Now, to clear the frame, you can use any of the following commands:

```
window.pack_forget()
window.destroy()
```

The final modified code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
content = tk.StringVar()
global window
window = ttk.Frame(root)

def startgame():
    global window
    window.pack_forget()
    window = ttk.Frame(root)
    number1 = random.randint(10, 51)
    number2 = random.randint(10, 51)
    sum_of_num = number1 + number2

    def checkresult():
        global content
        i = int(content.get())
        if i == sum_of_num:
            label = tk.Label(window, text = "Correct Result", fg = "blue").pack()
        else:
            label = tk.Label(window, text = "Incorrect result!! Try again.", fg = "red").pack()


    root.title("Number Guessing Game")
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "Let's begin the Quiz", fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "---------------------", fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "Given two numbers", fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = number1, fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = number2, fg = "blue").pack()
    label = tk.Label(window, text = "Add these two numbers and enter the result", fg = "blue").pack()

    sum_of_numbers = tk.Entry(window, textvariable = content)
    sum_of_numbers.pack()
    sum_of_numbers.focus_set()

    button_to_check_result = tk.Button(window, text="Check whether answer is correct", fg = "red", command = checkresult).pack()
    window.pack()

startgame()    
button_to_try_again = tk.Button(root, text="Try Again !!", fg = "red", command = startgame).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this whole segment as a function:

```
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Let's begin the Quiz", fg = "blue").pack()
label = tk.Label(window, text = "---------------------", fg = "blue").pack()
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Given two numbers", fg = "blue").pack()
label = tk.Label(window, text = number1, fg = "blue").pack()
label = tk.Label(window, text = number2, fg = "blue").pack()
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Add these two numbers and enter the result", fg = "blue").pack()
```

Then bind that function to the 'Reset' button that you are planning to implement. Or if you want to reset each time the user presses the 'Check' button, then you can call the function within checkresult().

Essentially what you will be doing is to display the new labels over the existing labels.

Comment: but how will the number1 and number2 update each time while pressing reset button

Comment: Basically this is the problem statement, "Create a new program that will generate two random whole numbers between 10 and 50.
It should ask the user to add the number and type in the answer. If they get the question correct, display suitable image as a
tick;
if they get the answer wrong display another suitable image such as cross. They should click on button to get another question." ,If u could help me out.

Comment: I have added another answer with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would define

```py
text_number1 = tk.StringVar()
text_number2 = tk.StringVar()
sum_of_num = 0
```

Then I would change startgame function to

```py
def startgame():
    global sum_of_num
    number1 = random.randint(10, 51)
    text_number1.set(str(number1))
    number2 = random.randint(10, 51)
    text_number2.set(str(number2))
    sum_of_num = number1 + number2
```

And labels accordingly

```py
label_num1 = tk.Label(window, textvar = text_number1, fg = "blue").pack() 
label_num2 = tk.Label(window, textvar = text_number2, fg = "blue").pack()
```

Next thing you need is your reset button

```py
button_to_check_reset = tk.Button(window, text="Reset your question", fg = "red", command = new_question).pack()
```

And last but not least new_question function

```py
def new_question()
    startgame()
    sum_of_numbers.delete(0, 'end')
```

that is bare minimum.

But if you want to have a program that won't have appearing and outdated labels you need to add one more stringvar to intialization for example

```py
answer_string = StringVar()
answer_string.set("Waiting for your answer")
```

Than put anwer lable right after other labels

```py
answer_lable = tk.Label(window, textvar = answer_string, fg = "blue").pack()
```

Then you need to reform check result function

```py
def checkresult():
        i = int(content.get())
        if i == sum_of_num:
            answer_lable['fg'] ="green"
            answer_string.set("Correct, that was not hard right?")
        else:
            answer_lable['fg'] ="red"
            answer_string.set("Wrong, you moron")
```

And a little modification to newquestion funct:

```py
def new_question()
    startgame()
    sum_of_numbers.delete(0, 'end')
    answer_lable['fg'] ="blue"
    answer_string.set("Waiting for your answer...")
```

I hope that will help and good luck :)

Comment: You will see I deleted global content and added global sum_of_num. Learn how global works and when is needed . That may save you some headache.